# How can I deal with recursion problem in such nested dictionary?

Tags: python

You've recieved a serialized JSON object from an API and have deserialized it using the standard library's json library. The object represents your geneology from a given ancestor downward. Assuming your name is Sally and your given ancestor is Janet, your geneology object would be as follows:

```
geneology_object = {
    'husband': 'Craig', 
    'wife': 'Janet',
    'children': {
        'Chris': {
            'husband': 'Chris', 
            'wife': 'Jesse',
            'children': {
                'Rebecca': {
                    'husband': 'Doug', 
                    'wife': 'Rebecca',
                }
            }
        },
        'Wonda': {
            'husband': 'Kevin', 
            'wife': 'Wonda',
            'children': {
                'Sally': {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Write a function with the signature get_generations_down(geneology_object, search_name, generations=0) to recursively search for the number of generations between search_name and the eldest ancestor. If the name is not found, a NameNotFoundError should be raised by the recursive function.

Assuming the geneology object above, your function should behave as so:

> get_generations_down(geneology_object, 'Chris') 1
>   get_generations_down(geneology_object, 'Sally') 2

My code is here,it doesn't work For 'Sally'

```py
class NameNotFoundError(Exception):
    pass

count=0

def get_generations_down(geneology_object, search_name, generations=0): 

    global count

    for i in geneology_object:
        if isinstance(geneology_object[i],dict):
            if i=='children':
                generations+=1
                if search_name in geneology_object[i]:
                    count+=1
                    break  

                return
get_generations_down(geneology_object[i],search_name,generations)

        elif i == search_name:
            count+=1
            break
        elif geneology_object[i]== search_name:
            count+=1
            break
        print(geneology_object)

    if count==0:
        raise NameNotFoundError


    return generations

    #raise NotImplementedError()


get_generations_down(geneology_object, 'Sally')
```

Comment: It's not my homework. I add my codes, I just want to figure out how to deal with this problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seem to be a recursive solution.

Here's how I worked it out,

```
class NameNotFoundError (Exception):
    pass

def get_generations_down(geneology_object, search_name, generations=0):
    found=False
    if ('husband' in geneology_object) and ('wife' in geneology_object) and (search_name == geneology_object['husband'] or search_name == geneology_object['wife']):
            return True,generations

    if 'children' in geneology_object:
        children=(geneology_object['children'])
        generations+=1

        if search_name in children:
            return True,generations
        else:
            for child in children:
                if found:
                    break
                found,generations=get_generations_down(geneology_object['children'][child],search_name,generations)

    else:
        generations-=1
    return found,generations


result = get_generations_down(geneology_object, 'Sally')

if(result[0]):
    print (result[1])
else:
    raise NameNotFoundError()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't  work if the name is not in geneology_object,for example, get_generations_down(geneology_object, 'D'), the function can't raise NameNotFoundError

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have fixed it in the edit. Replaced **in** with **==** in the line `(search_name in geneology_object['husband'] or search_name in geneology_object['wife'])`